# Masstransit: PublishFault context.Message is null when broker not reachable

Tags: rabbitmq, masstransit

I am implementing fail over solution for messages published with Masstransit when the actual broker (RabbitMQ) is down.
The idea is to grab failed messages store them somewhere and then republish when the broker is up and running.

Possible solution is to use PublishObserver with implementation of PublishFault method.

Version of Masstransit is 5.5.5

```
public Task PublishFault<T>(PublishContext<T> context, Exception exception) where T : class
    {
        var message = context.Message; // message is null
        ..... // logic to save fault message in persistent storage
    }
```

Expected result is to have an access to context.Message

Actual result - the context.Message is null;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been fixed in the develop version of MassTransit, which should be released at some point (as 5.5.6).

https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/pull/1546